# How can I generate a list of html elements on a particular page?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am adding a help text model to my rails app, which allows admins to create help text for pages on my site.  The form that allows admins to make help text requires text, location, and admin name.  I would like the location attribute to have two input fields.  The first being the particular page, and the second being the exact html element that the help text is to appear in.

How can I generate a list of the elements on the specified page?

Once the location is selected, I will build a helper to convert that into an xpath.  From there, the help text and icon(s) will be added to the page via JavaScript.

If this approach isn't the most effective, what might be another method?  RubyGems, scripts, rails magic, etc.

TL;DR How can I generate a list of html elements only knowing the page.

Comment: So you're writing a piece of Javascript that scans the page currently loaded into the browser and gives back all DOM nodes with text in?

Comment: I'd like to grab the elements of a page that is specified in the form.  For example, if an admin selects the 'Search Page', I want to grab the elements of the Search Page (which is not the page the admin is on) and display them as select options in the form.